# T-SQL Writing a Count Statement to find two values

Tags: sql, t-sql, count

I am trying to get two columns to appear. I have made a union of number of tables together. These tables then appear in one table now.

After this table I know need to do a summary count of one column.

This column contains two values. So i require to get count on text value 1 and text value 2 in the column.

```
select count (column_name) as column_name
FROM table name
where column_name = 'value1'
```

But i am not sure how to add value 2 into this statement? Any help be great. Much appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the table and the desired result? Are you trying to select it as one column or different columns (based of value)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pivot`, but I think conditional aggregation is easier in this case:

```
select sum(case when column_name = 'value1' then 1 else 0 end) as value1,
       sum(case when column_name = 'value2' then 1 else 0 end) as value2       
from table name;
```

If you can live with the values on two rows instead of in two columns, use `group by`:

```
select column_name, count(*)
from table name
group by column_name;
```

Comment: select column_name, count (*) FROM table name group by column_name where column_name in ( 'value1' ,'value2')

I think this has helped. The only issue I got is, I have just used a union on 10 tables. Now this table exists, how can I use this against that table as FROM statement will not work against it as the table does not exist.

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

```
select column_name, count (*) 
FROM 
( 
     select column_name from table1
     union all
     select column_name from table2
) src
group by column_name
where column_name in ( 'value1' ,'value2')
```

Comment: This is what I am looking for. Only issue is the from statement, how do I select from if the table I created is joined by unions so is not a physical table. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

I not sure what you want but whatever I understand, I think this will help you -

```
select 
    Sum ( case when column_name = 'value1'  then 1 else 0 end) as CountValue1,
    Sum ( case when column_name = 'value2'  then 1 else 0 end) as CountValue2
 FROM table name
```